# How do you change the position of a component to keep it same as the v-model it's bound to?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 sliders. When the value of the lower slider is greater than 0, the top slider must be 5. I use a watcher to achieve this. But if I change the position of the top slider, it doesn't "snap" back to the 5 position. The value is still 5 though, it's just visually not moving. How do I get it return to the position it should be at?

https://jsfiddle.net/omz36csL/29/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card class="pa-5 ma-2">
      <v-row v-for="(dummy, index) in dummyData" :key="index">
        <v-slider v-model="dummyData[index]" :min="0" :max="5" type="numbers" single-line hide-details>
        </v-slider>
        <v-chip>{{dummyData[index]}}</v-chip>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    dummyData: [1, 0]
  },
  watch: {
    dummyData(val) {
      if (val[1] > 0) {
        this.dummyData[0] = 5
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: I think this has something to do with v-model getting broken between the vuetify slider and the form input inside their component. Because you are trying to change the value of the thing you are watching for changes to happen in. If that makes sense. For instance, I can make it work like you want if I use a native text input and try to change the value it will not let me. There, we have no vuetify in between to try to pass the v-model down into.

Comment: I think if you are to stay with this component, but also as a better bit of UX, you should consider disabling the first slider if the second slider is over 0. That way you are not recursively watching setting watching the same element. And on the UX side, you don't tease the user with having a control that they shoudln't be able to interact with enabled and changing on them when they try to change it themselves.

Comment: @camwhite I tried that, it doesn't solve the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: @innerurge1 Disabling isn't an option. There are conditions where I want slider A to be constrained to the value 4 or 5 if slider B is greater than 0.

Vuetify I don't think is the issue. For example it works fine if I just use a v-chip, or a v-text-field. But it doesn't work if I use sliders or radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Waching a computed property is generally a better idea.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    dummyData: [1, 0]
  },
  methods: {
   doThis() {
      if (this.dummy > 0) {
        this.dummyData[0] = 5
      } 
   }
  },
  watch: {
    dummy: "doThis"
  },
  computed: {
   dummy () {
     return this.dummyData[1];
   }
  }
});
```

EDIT:

```
<v-slider
  v-model="dummyData[index]"
  :min="0" :max="5" type="numbers" single-line hide-details 
  :class="{'no-pointer-events': index === 0 && dummyData[index + 1] > 0}">
</v-slider>

.no-pointer-events {pointer-events: none}
```

Comment: computed has the same results as using a watch. I chose to use watch because you need a getter and setter for the computed to use it properly as the v-model.

Comment: I don't use computed property as v-model. Please read the code carefully. Computed properties and watchers aren't the same or alternatives to each other.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I now understand what you meant. I implemented it as you suggested, but it didn't work. The variables are still the correct values, but the slider position doesn't change. The v-chip updates fine though.

Comment: Please copy my code and past it directly in your Fiddle. Don't change anything on HTML and don't forget to click "RUN". I've just done it, and it works.

Comment: I copied it and it doesn't work. It does what it does before, i.e. move the first slider to 5 if the second slider is > 0. But I can move the first slider to any other value still and it doesn't move back to 5.

Comment: I don't understand how difficult it can be to make it run. https://jsfiddle.net/o1pbvLet/

Comment: I tried in chrome, firefox, and edge. It still doesn't work as it intended. When you move the first slider, it stays at the new number and doesn't snap back to 5.

Comment: I didn't code that feature since I did understand it wrong when I read your message in the first place. I did try a few methods. The only one that worked is to prevent dragging if the bottom slider > 0. (I edited my answer).

Comment: Thanks. I think there is no real way to do it. I think I need to make a custom component for it.